# Databricks ADD_NODES_FAILED: Failed to add 2 containers to the compute NETWORK_CONFIGURATION_FAILURE(CLIENT_ERROR)

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

Scenario - We have a Databricks job cluster that executes a notebook multiple times via parallel tasks (with different parameters) to process data from one layer to another. The job is set to use a 'Continuous' trigger. It has been configured to use 13.3 LTS (Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12), Photon and has 1 driver and 1 worker. The job executes successfully most of the time, but sporadically fails with the following error:

> Unexpected failure while waiting for the cluster (xxx) to be ready:
> Cluster xxx is in unexpected state Terminated:
> NETWORK_CONFIGURATION_FAILURE(CLIENT_ERROR):
> databricks_error_message:Failed to launch
> HostedContainer{hostPrivateIP= xxx, containerIp=xxx, clusterId=xxx,
> resources=InstantiatedResources{memoryMB=249480, ECUs=31.0,
> cgroupShares=31744}, isSpot=false, id=yyy, instanceId=InstanceId(zzz),
> state=Pending, instanceType=Standard_E32d_v4,
> metadata=ContainerMetadata(Standard_E32d_v4)} because starting the
> FUSE daemon timed out. This may happen because your VMs do not have
> outbound connectivity to DBFS storage. Also consider upgrading your
> cluster to a later spark version.,instance_id:zzz.

Any pointers on troubleshooting or cluster config updates that may resolve this issue?

Comment: Did it work before? Are any other clusters running in that workspace successfully?

Comment: yes, the job works fine most of the time, it fails because of this error intermittently. I have updated the cluster config to use runtime 12.2 LTS (Scala 2.12, Spark 3.3.2). Working fine for now.

Comment: I would recommend to open a support ticket, but really it could be some networking/firewall issue